# Storing and Retrieving images from sql server 2012 using vb6

Tags: image, vb6

I want to develop a solution to insert user pic into database after user clicks load. Then clicking view will display the user pic stored in the DB of that user identified by uid.

Module Code:
http://pastebin.com/CTW3e0ez

Form Code:
http://pastebin.com/W0CNUuJ1

The problem is that due to the presence of

```
rs.AddNew
rs.Fields("ID").Value = ID
rs.Fields("Description").Value = Description
rs.Fields("Picture").Value = strStream.Read
rs.Update
```

I cannot use SQL **insert into** with **where** clause.

My main intention is to allow an user to change his profile picture. And after the file is selected, it will be stored in DB and also displayed in the pictue box.

Comment: you have problem in adding record or updating record ? If it is insertion, why where clause ?

Comment: I have problem in checking the username while adding the record.

Comment: Still not clear.  If you are adding there is no username to check for, so do you actually mean update instead of add?  Yes, I am asking the previous question again.

Comment: See this pic : http://i.imgur.com/VOmfm0d.jpg

Comment: That would be an UPDATE...WHERE, not an INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

Well you ought to be able to do this using a Command object with anonymous parameters, as defined in this simple open routine:

```
Public Sub OpenDB()
    Set conDB = New ADODB.Connection
    conDB.Open strConn

    Set cmndUpdate = New ADODB.Command
    With cmndUpdate
        .Name = "Update"
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = "UPDATE [PicTable] " _
                     & "SET [Picture] = ? " _
                     & "WHERE [ID] = ?"
        Set .ActiveConnection = conDB
    End With
End Sub
```

This can be invoked later as a dynamic method of the Connection, as in:

```
Private Sub cmdReplace_Click()
    'We have an open Recordset (RS) to get the ID from.  We use the
    'current record's ID and update that record with a fixed photo
    'file "photo 04.jpg" just for demonstration:
    Dim PictureFileName As String
    Dim PictureFile As Integer
    Dim PictureBlob() As Byte

    PictureFile = FreeFile(0)
    Open "photos\photo 04.jpg" For Binary Access Read As #PictureFile
    ReDim PictureBlob(LOF(PictureFile) - 1)
    Get #PictureFile, , PictureBlob
    Close #PictureFile

    conDB.Update PictureBlob, RS!ID.Value

    'Repaint our user interface by calling our ShowData subroutine,
    'which displays data from the current record of RS:
    ShowData
End Sub
```

I did a quick and dirty test using a Jet MDB, but I see no reason why this shouldn't work for most SQL Server versions beyond old 6.5 or so.  Since it doesn't use named parameters it should even work with SQL Server Compact Edition.

See [SQL Parameters Example](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?726339-VB6-SQL-Parameters-Example&p=4451607#post4451607) for a more complete, testable example.